# Would Hex disadvantage non-proficient skill checks made with the associated attribute?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

If Hex causes "disadvantage on ability checks made with the chosen ability", and non-proficient skill checks are effectively just an ability check with no prof bonus added, would those checks be at disadvantage?

Comment: What skill checks?  This isn't 3.5e.  If you could [review chapter 7 of the basic rules](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=60) and revise this question that would be great.

Comment: I'm rolling back the recent edit, because the OP's confusion in that regard seems to be the basis of their misunderstanding/confusion regarding the spell.

Answer (score 19):

### Yes, because skill checks are ability checks, proficient or not

You seem to have mistakenly assumed a mechanical difference between a "skill check" and an "ability check" - but understandably so, as in previous editions there was a meaningful difference between the terms. In 5e, all skill checks *are* ability checks, [as per the basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#Skills) (emphasis mine):

> Sometimes, the DM might ask for an ability check using a specific skill--for example, “Make a Wisdom (Perception) check.” At other times, a player might ask the DM if proficiency in a particular skill applies to a check. In either case, *proficiency in a skill means an individual can add his or her proficiency bonus to ability checks that involve that skill*. Without proficiency in the skill, the individual makes a normal ability check.

Proficiency in a skill allows you add your proficiency bonus to relevant ability checks, but doesn't stop them being ability checks. *Hex* would cause disadvantage on all ability checks involving the targeted ability, whether skill proficiency applies or not.

An important distinction to keep in mind when adjudicating *Hex* is that attack rolls and saving throws are *not* ability checks. People usually remember that attack rolls are their own thing, but it's a common misconception that a saving throw is a kind of ability check; however, attack rolls, saving throws, and ability checks are each mechanically distinct kinds of roll, and *Hex* doesn't hinder a creature's saving throws.

Comment: Absolutely correct. Everyone, repeat after me, "There is no such thing as a skill check." :-)

Comment: I think there is also a lot of confusion between an _"ability check"_ and a _"saving throw"_. Saving throws are, "an attempt to resist a spell, a trap, a poison, a disease, or a similar threat. You don't normally decide to make a saving throw; you are forced to make one because your character or monster is at risk of harm." Whereas a skill check, "represents a specific aspect of an ability score, and an individual's proficiency in a skill demonstrates a focus on that aspect." Hex only effects skill checks, whereas combat spells call for saving throws.

Answer (score 6):

Hex causes the chosen ability's checks to be made with Disadvantage, irrespective of whether the target has proficiency (or expertise!) in a skill with said ability or not. So you don't need to take proficiency into account for this effect.